# OSX Safari skips javascript functions when data is posted to an SSL URL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ssl, safari

When a form's submit button is pressed, I want to disable the submit buttons and show a hidden div. My code:

HTML:

```
<div id="processing" class="processing">this should be visible when submit is pressed.</div>
<form action="https://url" method="post" id="id" name="id">
<input class="input1" type="reset" value="Reset">
<input class="input1" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Javascript:

```
$("form").one("submit", function() {
    action();
});

function action() {
    document.getElementById('processing').style.display = 'block';
    $(":submit").replaceWith('&nbsp;');
    $(":reset").replaceWith('&nbsp;');
    alert("end");
}
```

css:

```
div.processing {
    display: none;
}
```

It works in Firefox and Safari for Windows. It does not work with Mac Safari with an SSL url.

Behavior in Mac Safari submitting the form to an SSL URL: Hit submit button -> alert end shows up -> data gets submitted

Behavior in Firefox and Safari for Windows with an SSL URL: Hit submit button -> buttons get replaced, alert pops up, and the div shows up -> data gets submitted

Behavior in Mac Safari submitting to a non-ssl  url: Hit submit button -> buttons get replaced, alert pops up, and the div shows up -> data gets submitted

Mac Safari version is 5.1.7.
Anyone know how to get it to behave properly when I submit the data from a secure url to another secure url? Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any errors in the browser console? As an aside, you can say `$("form").one("submit",action)`, you don't need the anonynous function. Or you can just put the contents of `action()` into the anonymous function. And since you're using jQuery, `$("#processing").show();` is easier than using `getElementById()` and setting the style property manually. And why not `$(":submit,:reset").hide()` - why the replace?

Comment: Thank you much, I'm trying to pick this stuff up. Now I'm cleaned down to: 
    $("form").one("submit",action);

        function action() {
         $("#processing").show();
         $(":submit,:reset").hide();
         alert("end");
        }
Still dealing with it not working right though. No errors in the error console.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I can't explain why it doesn't work for that SSL case. (Just thought I'd give you that tidy-up tip in the meantime.)

Comment: Can you browse to that `https://` URL (anything on that server) directly on OSX, without any warning?

Comment: nnnnnn, Thanks!  Bruno, yes. I've made all sorts of pages on it to try too.